# apache htaccess using conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wanna use conditions in htaccess and if it was true use some rewrite rules.
for example my idea is:

```
if(subdomain='en' OR query string have '[lan=en]'){
    RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^user/1.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]
    .....
}elseif(subdomain='fa' OR query string have '[lan=fa]'){
    RewriteRule ^home.html$ index_fa.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^karbar/1.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]
    .....
}
```

how I can do it?
Is any way to use different .htaccess file for each conditions too?

**NOTE:** my domain address and my query string are dynamic

Comment: You can do it by reading the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), especially the part about `RewriteCond`

Comment: my problem is I have many RewriteRules and RewriteCond support only one rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then use rules like this in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lan=en(&|$)
RewriteRule ^home\.html$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lan=en(&|$)
RewriteRule ^user/1\.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fa\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lan=fa(&|$)
RewriteRule ^home\.html$ index_fa.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fa\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lan=fa(&|$)
RewriteRule ^karbar/1\.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a set of `RewriteCond` directives with multiple `RewriteRule` directives, but in a roundabout way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^en\. [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lan=en(&|$)
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^home\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^user/1\.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fa\. [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lan=fa(&|$)
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^home\.html$ index_fa.php [L]
RewriteRule ^karbar/1\.html$ user.php?id=1 [QSA,L]
```

The `[S=2]` flag in the `RewriteRule` directives means "skip next 2 rules"; thus the rules read like this: "If `HTTP_HOST` does not start with `en.` *and* `QUERY_STRING` does not contain `lan=en`, skip the next two rules"; thus the next two rules are considered *only* when the above conditions do *not* match.